# Why bucket policy is used?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a question about s3 bucket access, it's so complecated for me.

my configuration for s3 bucket is "public access is denied"

when I don't specify any policy in s3 bucket policy and give a user predefined S3 readonly permission, I can bring list of buckets and list of object in buckets.

But when I only make bucket policy for the user who has no iam policy attached to list buckets and object. the user are not able to list buckets and objects.

If it is true, why bucket policy is necessary to use?

bucket policy I made is like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1672363253371",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt16",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2040:user/viewer"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket"
        }
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt17",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2040:user/viewer"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The IAM policy controls permissions for **your** user to access **any** bucket, while the bucket policy controls permissions for **any** user to access **your** bucket. Both policies are required in order to grant access **unless** the same account owns both the user and the bucket, and that is the overlap you are seeing. When both the user and the bucket are owned by the same account then either policy can grant a permission as long as the other policy does not deny it.

Comment: Thank you, Jain. I was wrong. bucket policy can give permission to specific user without iam policy specified.